# How to set a css to not loose hover effect after visited link?

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

This is how it is currently:

```
/* OCSearch Texto */
.linksearch {
color: #fff;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left: 20px;
font-size: 12px;    
}

.linksearch a:link {
color:#d8d8d8;
}

.linksearch a:hover {
color:#fff;
}

.linksearch a:visited {
color:#d8d8d8;
}
```

When clicked out the color changes to #d8d8d8 but theres no more hover after that. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried moving your `:hover` rule below the `:visited` rule/ further down the cascade order?

Comment: What @UncaughtTypeError said. Reorder your `:hover` to be after the `:visited`.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't realize the order would influence this. Thanks!

Comment: @RafaelPrado Cascade order is `!important` with regards to CSS. Typically, rules further down the cascade order over-qualify rules declared higher up the cascade order - unless the rules have more selectors defined or utilize the `!important` declaration.

Comment: I would not recommend going down the `!important` rabbit hole in this circumstance. This is a good resource regarding cascading, inheritance and specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate your `:hover` and `:visited` declarations to solve this. Also, don't neglect the `:focus` pseudo for keyboard users. Especially if you are using a reset that removes the `outline` from focusable items.

```
/* OCSearch Texto */
.linksearch {
  ...   
}

.linksearch a:visited {
    color:#d8d8d8;
}

.linksearch a:hover, .linksearch a:focus {
    color:#fff;
}
```